# Building a Unity Standalone with .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine

In order to build a standalone of a particular project, I have to choose `.NET 2.0` in the `Player Settings` (instead of the default selection `.NET 2.0 Subset`) but by doing so, when running the standalone, the app becomes **unusable** due to being **extremely slow**.

I have Oculus Rift hooked up, so it literally becomes one frame per 10 seconds. It just does not run...

What do I do to resolve this? The project only builds with `.NET 2.0` and the resulting standalone is so incredibly slow that the app becomes unusable...

Thanks

Comment: Run it through a decent profiler.  There are a few, such as [Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

Comment: Why do you think your problem is .NET 2.0 setting? Did you already tried set .NET 2.0 in some unity sample project and build an standalone to test if your performance issue is actually related to this setting? (sorry but it is not clear to me as in your question you mentioned that you can't just build standalone with subset, it appears that you don't really know if your standalone issue is directly related to this particular setting )

Comment: Hi Frohlich.  Thanks for your comment that made me re-think why I thought `.NET 2.0` was the problem!  I thought so, because switching between the two _seemed_ to make the problem go away a few times, but in fact, this was not the source of the issue, thanks to your suggestion to replicate it all in a different sample project.